# Different UI Design behaviour in react-native (expo)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, expo

I'M creating ui in expo application using `react-native-paper`.   The UI is getting different for android and iOS platform for Account Screen.   However, i tried same code in Snack and it show correct ui in web.


This is ios UI
[image]


This is android UI
[image]

In Android, some part of ui is hidden.

[Snack Code Link](https://snack.expo.io/@darkkiller/carefree-apples)

I need look like ios device screenshot have in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is demo: https://snack.expo.io/@nomi9995/45f132

You should make parent view inside ScrollView and wrap ImageBackground and View
inside this parent view

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  ImageBackground,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";
import { FontAwesome, MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { TextInput, Button } from "react-native-paper";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

export default function App() {
  const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;
  const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, height: SCREEN_HEIGHT }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, height: SCREEN_HEIGHT }}>
          <ImageBackground
            source={{
              uri:
                "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ielts-preps.appspot.com/o/1592920135765?alt=media&token=ec911583-06f9-4315-b66c-cf47de120e85",
            }}
            style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.4 }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                alignItems: "flex-start",
                margin: 20,
              }}
            >
              <FontAwesome name="close" size={30} color="#fff" />
              <MaterialIcons name="edit" size={30} color="#fff" />
            </View>
          </ImageBackground>
          <View
            style={{
              height: SCREEN_HEIGHT * 2,
              width: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.9,
              backgroundColor: "red",
              position: "absolute",
              left: (SCREEN_WIDTH - SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.9) / 2,
              top: SCREEN_HEIGHT * 0.3,
              zIndex: 1,
              elevation: 10,
            }}
          >
            <TextInput
              label="First Name"
              value=""
              mode="flat"
              onChangeText={(text) => {}}
              style={{ margin: 20, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}
            />

            <TextInput
              label="Last Name"
              value=""
              mode="flat"
              onChangeText={(text) => {}}
              style={{ margin: 20, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}
            />

            <Button
              style={{
                marginHorizontal: 50,
                marginVertical: 20,
                backgroundColor: "#0af",
                padding: 10,
              }}
              mode="contained"
              onPress={() => {}}
            >
              Update
            </Button>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Then why the behavior in iOS is perfect ??

Comment: there is a concept of view manager in virtual dom that is creating a problem because it behave differently in android and in ios